# How can I count the nodes of a data structure if a child has multiple parents?

Tags: java

I need help with an assignement in java...so, I have a `TreeNode` class that looks like this...this is the way we were asked to do this so I am not allowed to change it.

```
class TreeNode{
int data;
TreeNode leftNode;
TreeNode rightNode;
public TreeNode(int data) {
     this.data=data;
}
```

}

The problem is that i have to create a method `int getNumOfNodes(TreeNode t)`  and will return the number of nodes in the structure.The thing is that i cannot figure out how to count the node with the value `9` only once since I am trying to use recursion for the left and right subtree and because this specific node has two parents it gets counted twice...Any ideas?

I am trying to create this structure(I am trying to explain it since I couldn;t post a pic)

```
           5
         /  \
        7    12
         \  /  \
          9      2
```

here is what I tried

```
 int getNumOfNodes (TreeNode t){


    if(t==null)
        return 0;


    return 1 + getNumOfNodes(t.leftNode) + getNumOfNodes(t.rightNode);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the code you wrote of you expect anyone to help you figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: How could I do that without counting the  Node with the number 9 twice?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect/find all the `TreeNode` objects first and put them in a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Since a `Set` cannot have duplicates, you add a node only once, even when you encountered it more than once. You can write a helper method like this:

```
private static Set<TreeNode> findAllNodes(TreeNode node) {
    Set<TreeNode> nodes = new HashSet<TreeNode>();
    nodes.add(node);
    if (node.leftNode != null) {
        Set<TreeNode> leftNodes = findAllNodes(node.leftNode);
        nodes.addAll(leftNodes);
    }
    if (node.rightNode != null) {
        Set<TreeNode> rightNodes = findAllNodes(node.rightNode);
        nodes.addAll(rightNodes);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

*(untested pseudo code)*

After that you can simply call `size()` to see how many nodes you have collected.

```
Set<TreeNode> allNodes = findAllNodes(t);
return allNodes.size();
```

Keep in mind that this pseudo code does not work for graphs with cycles.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!The thing is trhat we have not been teached about Sets yet so I can't use your solution...I will consider using it if I cannot find any other way...Is there something else you can suggest?

Comment: @Aristotelis Then use a `List`, but then you have to use `contains()` by yourself to check if you have already added the element to the container or not so you don't add the node twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I am going to use your method...I was trying to find a solution without using a List but I am starting to think that's not even possible..